# How to correctly create Web Service with WHERE clause preventing injection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, asmx

Not sure where to post this question, but I am concerned about the security of the answer so I targeted here.

I have a web service running that reliably returns a dataset and allows me to provide a list now drop down list box of records returned.

I would like to capture the users selection from the DDL and call another web service to return detailed information regarding the selection. Hence a WHERE stmt in the query of the web service. I am of course worried about SQL injection. But I would ike to at least get the SQL stmt working.

The selection is a string field type, and looks like this,

```
<WebMethod()> Public Function getDBrecords(ByVal FileName As String) As DataSet
    Return GetDataSet("SELECT ID, ptMaster_ID, StrName, LngText, ShrtText,  Lcode, Name, FROM tblMstStrng WHERE FileName = """ & FileName & """; ")
End Function
```

No luck, it crashes my app with a SOAP error.

"Unable to automatically step into the server. Attaching to the server proces failed. A dbugger is already attached."

And after I clear that Message box....

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException was unhandled
  Actor=""
  Lang=""
  Message="System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'DD_EBSKW20_380_db.pts'.    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)    at stringInfo.GetDataSet(String strSQL) in C:\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Code\stringInfo.vb:line 32    at stringInfo.getDBrecords(String dbName) in C:\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Code\stringInfo.vb:line 74    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---"
  Node=""
  Role=""
  Source="System.Web.Services"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at MultiLangWeb.localhost.stringInfo.getDBrecords(String dbName) in C:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MultiLangWeb\MultiLangWeb\Web References\localhost\Reference.vb:line 118
       at MultiLangWeb.Main.Button6_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MultiLangWeb\MultiLangWeb\Main.Designer.vb:line 388
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at MultiLangWeb.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Everything works for other web services if I remove the query with the WHERE clause.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the fact this is a web service. Try executing the same code from a Console application and you'll get the same result.

Comment: try to use vbVerticalTab to escape " character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the problem does not look like related to being a web service, why don't you just run a profiler on the server to see what command exactly goes to the sql server?

the other thing is you query: it's recommended to use stored procedures. not only for ease of management but more importantly for the sake of security.

you can find a brilliant article from microsoft msdn magazine here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/magazine/hh708755.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Once you get your other issues worked out that don't pertain to your actual question, you just need to parameterize your input. So your query literal would become:
    `"SELECT ID, ptMaster_ID, StrName, LngText, ShrtText,  Lcode, Name, FROM tblMasterStringPTS WHERE FileName = @FileName"`


I'm not sure exactly what your implementation is for retrieving your dataset, but I'm assuming you've got a SqlCommand object in there somewhere. To add the parameter
      
  `command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FileName", FileName))`
should be pretty close to what you need.

And there you go, no SQL injection risk.

For more info, visit [this MSDN link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht4eset1.aspx#Y389)

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that SQL Server `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` setting is `ON`, so it is treating the file name as a column name since it is embedded in double-quotes.

You can fix this by changing:

```
FileName = """ & FileName & """
```

to

```
FileName = "'" & FileName & "'"
```

That is why you are receiving this execption:

```
Invalid column name 'DD_EBSKW20_380_db.pts'
```

The second problem is that this is completely open to SQL injection attacks. You should either have the called method add a parameter to the command that is being executed, execute the sql as a stored procedure with the filename as a parameter, or (least recommended) attempt to clean any potential SQL injection characters (namely ' and ;) from the file name yourself before submitting.